# How to update Python version of my conda environment without loosing packages

Tags: python-3.x, conda

I have Python 3.6 installed in my conda environment but I have to update it to the newer 3.10 version to be able to install newest versions of some packages. How can I update Python version in such a way that my already installed packages will also be updated if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the environment:

```
conda install python=3.10
```

... and as always [read the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python)